# Join three table to get some problem help me?

Tags: php, sql

I Want to fetch data three tables **"category, subcategory, products"** but i have to get some error

> **Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
>   D:\xammp\htdocs\tam\admin\edit-products.php on line 157**

**PHP SQL**

```
<?php   
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from  products.*,

                       category.categoryName as catname,

                       subcategory.subcategory as categoryName

                       from products join category on 

                       category.cid=products.cid 

                       join subcategory on subcategory.sid=products.sid

                       where products.id='$id'");

       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))// line 157
        { ?> 

           }?>
```

Comment: check mysqli_query statement.use if else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did wrong selection it should be like below

```
select products.*,
       category.categoryName as catname,
       subcategory.subcategory as categoryName
  from products 
  join category 
    on category.cid=products.cid 
  join subcategory 
    on subcategory.sid=products.sid
 where products.id=?
```